# How do I solve: You're using Python 0.0. Some features might not work as expected since Visual Studio no longer supports this version?

Tags: visual-studio, virtual-environment, python-3.10

I am trying to create a virtual environment in Visual Studio. I created Python Project and have installed Python 3.10. I selected "Add Environment...", named it and selected a requirements.txt file. It takes about 20 minutes to create the environment, so I already created more. However, even when the tasks are completed, I cannot use them as they do not read the appropriate Python version. How do I solve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have found it is a bug and have downgraded tot 3.9